# FlashPro encountered a fatal exception. FlashPro will now terminate

Tags: flash

When I'm trying to open some  *fla files with adobe cs6...I got this error:

> "FlashPro encountered a fatal exception. FlashPro will now terminate. A log of the program's internal state at the time of the exception has been saved in this file on your desktop:
>   FlashPro crash log.mdmp
>   Please report this exception by entering a bug with the log file.
>   This file will help us in tracking down the source of the error."

and my flash is going to be closed after I press ok.

If you know how to fix this error, tell me please.

Comment: Post the log file.

Comment: Please edit the relevant contents of the log file into the question. The comment with the link was flagged as spam and deleted.

Comment: What is weird that, when, I encounter this error, on Adobe's bug report form, there is no way to attach a file, so I can't send them the memory dump without uploading it onto my website and giving them the link.

Comment: @ChrisF It's a memory dump (binary) file, so it would be unfeasible and unwieldy to paste its contents here.